Identifying the centroid, incenter, circumcenter, and orthocenter of a triangle from a set of vector equations
Now the question is:

Let $P_i$, with $i=1,2,3,4$, be points lying in plane of $\triangle A_1 A_2 A_3$, satisfying
$$\begin{align}
&\;\overrightarrow{P_2 A_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_2 A_2} + \overrightarrow{P_2 A_3} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_2 P_1} \\
=&\;\overrightarrow{P_2 A_3} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_2 A_1}+\overrightarrow{P_2 A_2} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_2 P_1} \\
=&\;\overrightarrow{P_2 A_2} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_2 A_3}+\overrightarrow{P_2 A_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_2 P_1}
\end{align} \tag1$$
$$\begin{align}
&\;\left|\overrightarrow{P_3 A_1}\right|^2-2\left(\overrightarrow{P_3 A_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_3 P_2}\right) \\
=&\;\left|\overrightarrow{P_3 A_2}\right|^2-2\left(\overrightarrow{P_3 A_2} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_3 P_2}\right) \\
=&\;\left|\overrightarrow{P_3 A_3}\right|^2-2\left(\overrightarrow{P_3 A_3} \cdot \overrightarrow{P_3 P_2}\right)
\end{align} \tag2$$
$$ \overrightarrow{P_1 A_1}+\overrightarrow{P_2 A_2}+\overrightarrow{P_3 A_3} \;=\; \overrightarrow{P_1 P_2}+2 \overrightarrow{P_2 P_3}+3 \overrightarrow{P_3 P_4} \tag3
$$
$$\begin{align}
&\;\left|\overrightarrow{A_1 P_1}-\overrightarrow{P_1 P_2}-
\overrightarrow{A_2 P_1}\right|\left(\overrightarrow{P_4 A_3}+\overrightarrow{P_3 P_4}\right) \\
+&\;\left| \overrightarrow{A_2 P_2}+\overrightarrow{P_2 A_3}\right|\overrightarrow{P_3 A_1} \\
+&\;\left| \overrightarrow{A_1 A_3} \right|\left(\overrightarrow{P_3 P_2}-\overrightarrow{A_2 P_2}\right) \\
=&\;\overrightarrow{0}
\end{align} \tag4$$

Now, match the points $P_i$ with corresponding points of $\triangle A_1 A_2 A_3$: centroid, incenter, circumcenter, orthocenter.
I am pondering over this question for a while but I unable to solve it. I think this question required high level of visualisation or is any mathematical approach to solve it?
The Original problem :


I re-formatted the equations in the hopes of making them easier to read. Please double-check the last one.

What is the source of this question? What can you tell us about the expected skill level of solvers?

BTW: Try expanding each $\overline{XY}$ as $Y-X$. Equation $(3)$ may be the best place to start. Then $(1)$ and $(2)$.

@Blue Thx for the edit. I have rechecked the last equation and corrected it. I am a high school student preparing for a bachelor degree college entrance exam and it was inside the preperation material.

Are you sure about that first factor in the last equation? From what I can tell, it "should" simplify to $|\overrightarrow{A_1A_2}|$. (Compare to the corresponding simplified factors in the other terms. Also ... spoiler ... $P_3$ is the incenter.) The original version of the equation didn't simplify to that, and neither does your edit. ... Incidentally, this turns out to be a nice little exercise, but it seems very time-consuming for an exam.

@Blue Ok I will add the image of the question

@Blue how P3 is incenter ?

Some physics relevance ( force, energy, work) of a triangle laminate might help reduce cumbersomeness in the problem solution? Not sure. No clue how such problems arose in the first place prior to setting them up!

@Narasimham: There's not really much great import to these relations. They're largely exercises in cancelling terms to leave elementary(-ish) identities. There may be some clever insights that reduce a bit of the symbol-pushing tedium, but brute force works pretty well. (It helps that we can expand each vector as the difference of points, and then formally treat the dot products as normal multiplication. So, at least in the cases of $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, manipulating the cognitively-heavy "vector relations" is effectively as easy as expanding and factoring polynomials.)

What book is this problem from?

To save typing and reduce confusion over subscripts, I'll define $A:=A_1$, $B:=A_2$, $C:=A_3$, and $P:=P_1$, $Q:=P_2$, $R:=P_3$, $S:=P_4$. (I'm ignoring the usage of these labels in the "Columns" in the original text of the problem.)
To identify the triangle centers from the equations, "all we have to do" is expand each $\overrightarrow{XY}$ as $Y-X$, and simplify.

Equation $(3)$:
$$\begin{align}
(A-P)+(B-Q)+(C-R) &\;=\; (Q-P)+2(R-Q)+3(S-R) \\[2pt]
\to\qquad A+B+C&\;=\;3S
\end{align}$$
So, $S$ (aka, $P_4$) is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$.

Subtracting the left-hand expression of $(1)$ from the "middle-hand" yields
$$(P-A)\cdot(C-B) = 0 \quad\to\quad \overline{AP}\perp\overline{BC}$$
Likewise, $\overline{BP}\perp\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{CP}\perp\overline{AB}$. So, $P$ (aka, $P_1$) is the orthocenter.

Similarly, from $(2)$, we get
$$(2Q-B-C)\cdot(B-C) = 0 \quad\to\quad \left(Q-D\right)\cdot(B-C) = 0 \quad\to\quad \overline{QD}\perp\overline{BC}$$
where $D:=\frac12(B+C)$ is the midpoint of side $\overline{BC}$. Likewise, $\overline{QE}\perp\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{QF}\perp\overline{AB}$, where $E$ and $F$ are corresponding midpoints. So, $Q$ (aka, $P_2$) is the circumcenter.

By process of elimination, $R$ (aka, $P_3$) must be the incenter. Let's see if this is consistent with equation $(4)$ by simplifying.
(Note: I'm using the version from the screenshot of the exercise. The equation has been mis-transcribed multiple times. This is understandable; as we'll see, even the problem's original typesetter got something wrong.)
$$\begin{align}
\left|
 \overrightarrow{AP}
-\overrightarrow{QP}
-\overrightarrow{BP}\right|
\left(\overrightarrow{SC}+\overrightarrow{RS}\right) +\left|\overrightarrow{BQ}+\overrightarrow{QC}\right|
\overrightarrow{RA} 
+\left| \overrightarrow{AC} \right|\left(\overrightarrow{RQ}-\overrightarrow{BQ}\right) 
&=0 \\[4pt]
\to\qquad 
|B-A+Q-P|(C-R)
+|C-B|(A-R) 
+|C-A|(B-R) 
&=0 \\[4pt]
\to\qquad 
a\overrightarrow{RA} 
\;+\;b\overrightarrow{RB}
\;+\;|B-A+Q-P|\overrightarrow{RC} &= 0
\end{align} $$
where $a:=|BC|$, $b:=|CA|$, $c:=|AB|$ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle. Now, it is "known" that
$$\begin{align}
a \overrightarrow{RA} 
+b \overrightarrow{RB}
+c \overrightarrow{RC}
&=0
\end{align}$$
This fact is often expressed as
$$R = \frac{a A + b B + c C}{a+b+c}$$
which gives $R$ as a weighted average of the triangle's vertices; in other words, the barycentric coordinates of $R$ are $a:b:c$ (just as the barycentric coordinates of the centroid are $1:1:1$, since $S=\frac{1A+1B+1C}{1+1+1}$).
So, the first factor of first term of the equation, $|B-A+Q-P|$, "should" reduce to $|A-B|$. But, in general, it doesn't. I suspect the typesetter wrote a $P_1$ for a $P_2$, or vice-versa, and that intended equation has (what I call) $P$ and $Q$ cancel. In that case, $R$ (aka, $P_3$) would indeed be the incenter; otherwise, $R$ is none of the given triangle centers.
